# How to play mp3s on my personal ASP.NET website?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have created an ASP.NET Website using VB.NET ASP.NET 4.0. Thing is, I want my visitors to hear some nice piano music as they browse my site. Now I don't know how to embed and play mp3s on an ASP.NET Website. So I need help with that.

Further, if the website visitor changes pages, music should pick up where it left off before the page change. Anyone have any idea of how to do this?

Help would be greatly appreciated! THANKS!!!

Comment: Would you pls take a look at this link ..., I hope it will helps you .. http://guy-lecky-thompson.suite101.com/how-to-put-mp3-file-in-web-page-a46092

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, but thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

Add an entry similar to this in your html code where the file address is relative to the html file or aspx file that is being shown.

I use netobjects fusion to create web pages: this is how the final page looks, the entry is just before the end tag for `<body>`:

```
<embed src="file:../yourfolder/yourfile.mp3" height="2" width="2" 
    autostart="true" hidden="true" loop="false">
</body>
```

If you want to know more, look up the `embed` tag in html documentation.

Comment: Sorry I cannot see the entry in your answer. Did you put any code in your answer?